# Spring Thymeleaf Hibernate Validation custom message not available on page

Tags: java, spring, validation, thymeleaf, hibernate-validator

In the example below I have a custom message on the @DecimalMin annotation.  From the output you can see that the default message is interpolated correctly in the controller method.

The issue is I would like to use this message on the html page.  The problem is thymeleaf grabs the first code in the codes list.  I would like it to use the custom code {grossPay.custom.message} but it has already been resolved.  Also it is not available as an error code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
//inside propery file
grossPay.custom.message=Dont do that

//inside model
@DecimalMin(value="0.00",message="{grossPay.custom.message}")

//inside controller
public String postResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myModel") CustomModel model, BindingResult result) {
for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()) {
                System.out.println("Field Error in field: " + error.getField() + " with default message: "+ error.getDefaultMessage());
                System.out.println("codes: ");
                for (String s : error.getCodes()) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
}

//output
Field Error in field: grossPay with default message: Dont do that
codes: 
DecimalMin.customModel.grossPay
DecimalMin.grossPay
DecimalMin.java.math.BigDecimal
DecimalMin
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by missing configuration. You need to define this in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3071